# C++ Assync only session with PHP (alive / dead)

Tags: php, c++

I wonder if there are ways to sync with the C ++ PHP (session alive / dead), such as when you try to enter again, 
the oldest session is automatically disconnected.

Could put the C ++ code associated with PHP?

Thank you.

Any tutorial ?

Post refer : https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?93716-C-Assync-only-session-with-PHP-(alive-dead)

Comment: Not exist any form/tutorial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with Curl library join (c++ with php)

Examples : 
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

Download : https://curl.haxx.se/download.html